# Modal dialague box exist even i click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a challenge dismissing a modal after successfully completing a delete operation.

Below is a screenshot of the modal in action:

[image: Confirm Delete modal]

When I click on a "Cancel" button, the modal gets dismissed as expected unlike the "Delete" button; even though with a successful operation.

What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Below are my codes;

*Modal dialogue box:*

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You are about to delete one track, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
                <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                <p class="debug-url"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*The code behind the button that triggers the modal dialogue box is:*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" id="delete" style="display: none;">Delete</button>
```

*Then, my script (to handle all operations):*

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var rowid = json_array['rowid'];
    $('.btn-ok').click( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete_record.php',
            type: "post",
            async: true,
            data: ({ row_id : rowid }),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
     });
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var rowid = json_array['rowid'];
    var instance = $(this);
    $('.btn-ok').click( function(){
        instance.modal('hide');                                        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete_record.php',
            type: "post",
            async: true,
            data: ({ row_id : rowid }),
            success: function(data) {
            }                                            
        });                                        
     });
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#modal').modal('toggle');`

Change the id/class and that should work. Basically toggle it to close if open and vice versa.

Comment: @RabelDinira Maximus got it ! :P